# What is Economic Interpretation of three nonlinear equations?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumption

I have the following nonlinear system

$w$ is wealth

$c$ is consumption

$r(w)$ is gross return on wealth

$a,b, d$ are parameters which are strictly positive and fixed.

$$\dot{w} =r(w)w-c$$

$$\dot{c}= a(w-b)$$

$$r(w)= 1+{d\over w^2}$$

I would like to make economic interpretation of these three equations.

—————

I can just say that

$${\partial r(w) \over \partial w}=-2{d\over w^3}<0$$ which means that as wealth increases, $r(w)$ will decrease.

$${\partial \dot{w}\over w} = {\partial r(w) \over \partial w}w+1+{d\over w^2} = 1-{d\over w^2}$$

which is positive if and only if $w>\sqrt{d}$.

So, under the condition $w>\sqrt{d}$, ${\partial \dot{w}\over \partial w} >0$ Which means that as wealth increases, $\dot {w}$ increases as well.

${\partial \dot{w}\over \partial c} >0$ Which means that as consumption increases, $\dot{w}$ decreases.

${\partial \dot{c}\over \partial w} >0$ Which means that as wealth increases, $\dot{c}$ increases as well.

——-

I have done these. Please share your opinions about interpretation. What is the economic meanings of these calculations?

Comment: You say $c$ is consumption and $c$ is a fixed parameter.  Is that the same $c$?

Comment: @AdamBailey thank you for your warning. I correct this typo. Right now it is right! What is your opinion?

Comment: You may also want to solve them and look at what factors determine the solutions of $w$ and $c$ to see how the return on wealth affects optimal levels of consumption and wealth.

Comment: @Brennan you are right! Well, can you show what you said? Because this is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: I don't think I have ever solved a system on non-linear differentials. I will give it a go over the next few days and see what I can come up with! Disclaimer it will be very complex if you aren't familiar with solving linear differential equations let alone non-linear differentials on their own. What level of studies are you at right now?

Comment: How familiar are you with differential equations? Your interpretation of the differentials is wrong, as these equations describe the evolution of a system through time (thus $\dot{w} \equiv \frac{dw}{dt}$). Are you supposed to be able to solve these equations? Or are you just looking to interpret the change of $w$ and $c$ through time? (i.e. interpret $\dot{w}$ and $\dot{c}$)

Comment: I am a new learner of differential equations. I tried to solve them, before interpreting. But I could not do it properly. Can you solve and interpret them as you said? I need to learn how to do such type of questions. Thank you so much. @user20105